# Generating a cache key (unique key) for a hash

Tags: ruby, caching

I have a hash, for example:

```
filers = {query: 'nice post', sort: 'time_desc', post_type: 'blog'...limit: 100}
```

which is used to filter response data. I need to create a unique key for this hash to cache the response. I can think of taking its keys and values and converting them into a single string. Looking for some interesting answers that are simple and efficient.

Comment: Might this work? http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-uuid

Comment: What is *the response* that you are mentioning?

Comment: @sawa, I mentioned response as the result set from an external api call using the above combination of filters. Yes I am using memcache to cache the response.

Answer (score 3):

Consider these following two steps:

1. Convert the Hash to a string (or other serialized format) after *sorting* the output write-order based on key.

   It is important that the values are sorted by key during this transformation so that Hashes with the same key/value pairs (but with a different key order) will yield the same output. More complicated/nested structures need additional handling and should ensure *consistent output* for equivalent objects.

   To get started with the process, consider:

   ```
   sorted_kv_pairs = hash.to_a.sort_by {|k,v| k.to_s}
   ```
2. Use a hashing function such as SHA-1 or SHA-256/160 to generate a 40-byte Unique ID from the previously serialized object.

   The *huge* output space (and cryptography qualities) of these functions make it unfeasible for there to be a purposeful collision and thus lead to "unique IDs".

Comment: I'd recommend to go with solution 2 above.

Comment: My mistake. Yeah. I agree. Step 1 followed by Step 2.

Comment: You could also use other hashing algorithms: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/145633/82539

Comment: @UriAgassi Thanks for the link. It's a handy answer/reference. However, I would use a cryptographic hash function with a *large* output space. Those hash/checksum functions (32-bit output) serve a different purpose (very fast checksum or primary hash with secondary equality), but have far less guarantees on "uniqueness". While they don't have many collisions and have good distribution over the random input (~ 200k) they are *far* more more likely go generate a duplicate than a SHA/cryptographic hash due to the birthday problem.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be using the [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Marshal.html) class to dump and read the content. For larger scales, you can use memcached, for which there are several Ruby wrappers, or some key-value databases like redis, neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23284942/518204)

```
# Return a cache key based on params hash
def params_cache_key(params)
  # Normalize parameter hash, change keys to a string, normalize key order, sort array values
  normalized = params.transform_keys(&:to_s)
                   .transform_values { |v| v.is_a?(Array) ? v.sort : v }
                   .sort_by { |k, _| k }.each_with_object('') do |(k, v), cache_key|
    cache_key << "#{k}:#{v}"
  end
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(normalized)
end
```

And here are some test cases

```
describe '#params_cache_key' do

  def cache_key(params)
    controller.send :params_cache_key, params
  end

  it 'should produce a sha1' do
    expect(cache_key(foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz')).to match /^\h{40}$/
  end

  it 'should produce same hash for different key order' do
    expect(cache_key(foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz')).to eq cache_key(bar: 'baz', foo: 'bar')
  end

  it 'should produce same hash for stringified keys' do
    expect(cache_key(foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz')).to eq cache_key(foo: 'bar', 'bar' => 'baz')
  end

  it 'should work with nested parameters in different order' do
    expect(cache_key(category: %w(foo bar))).to eq cache_key(category: %w(bar foo))
  end

end
```

Comment: Yeah, this code gets complicated soon. Don't forget about nested arrays and hashes. So I would say it is impossible to guarantee same data to generate the same hash, given different sort orders. Just sort on first level key should be enough.

Comment: your method `cache_key` in the spec is referring to `controller `, take this out